# Obtain Carbon difference between two dates in 15 minute increments

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-carbon

The following code will return the difference between two Carbon dates in minutes:

```
$carbonNow = Carbon::now();
$diff = $carbonNow->diffInMinutes($someRandomFutureDateVariable);
```

Which will return a single minute result. But I'm trying to get the difference in a 15 minute increments - such as every timestamp for every 15 minute increment in the result. Pseudo code would be:

```
[
    '2020-10-15 12:45:00',
    '2020-10-15 13:00:00',
    '2020-10-15 13:15:00',
    '2020-10-15 13:30:00',
    ...
]
```

In addition, I'd like to be able to set the time difference, so if I didn't want to target a 15 minute increment I could target whatever increment I pass into my function. I'm able to get the difference between two dates, but stuck on returning timestamps per each increment.

Comment: Suppose the difference in minutes is 22. Would the result you want be 15 because 15 is only 7 removed from 22 whereas 30 is 8 removed?

Comment: The difference incrementor would be passed in. 15 is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

carbon::diffInMinutes delivers the minutes and removes the seconds.

The minute difference for a given minute increment can easily be calculated as follows:

```
$inc = 15;  //15 minutes

$carbonNow = Carbon::now();
$diff = $carbonNow->diffInMinutes($someRandomFutureDateVariable);

$diffInc = $diff - $diff%$inc;
```

Comment: And how would you get the timestamps per each `$inc` increment?

Comment: Secondly, I'm not sure if your code example is working. The `$diff` and `$diffInc` results are only off by a few digits when I run a test locally.

Comment: diffInMinutes supplies the time difference in minutes as an integer. There is no timestamp for this.
You can only get a TimeStamp from a Date / Time object. Your question contradicts your pseudocode. You should specify what you want.

Comment: Or do you want to bring the date/time to a full 15 minutes? 2020-10-16 19:58:23 -> 2020-10-16 19:45:00